# Definition : The Distribution of laplacian of a function?

Tags: definition, distribution-theory

Let $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$(but i think we can be way more general than than).

How is $\langle\Delta u,\phi\rangle$ (distribution) defined for $\phi \in D(\Omega)$ a test function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most definitions in distribution theory, it boils down to "formal integration by parts":

$$\langle \Delta u,\phi \rangle = -\langle \nabla u,\nabla \phi \rangle = \langle u,\Delta \phi \rangle.$$

In general when doing this you need to be careful to be sure that the boundary terms in each of these integrations actually vanish in your setting. In the case described in the question this is trivial since $\phi \in D(\Omega)$.

Comment: Since $D(\Omega)$ consists of functions with compact support the boundary terms will automatically vanish.

Comment: @md2perpe In the usual setup of distribution theory, it's automatic; but people are often doing distribution theoretic-type calculations in PDE applications where boundary terms don't always drop out.

Comment: But the OP writes "for $\phi \in D(\Omega)$".

Comment: @md2perpe Good point, I revised that comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\langle \Delta u, \phi \rangle := \langle u, \Delta\phi \rangle.
$$